# ¿Como puedo mover un objeto en cualquier direccion? ADT Laberinto Java

Tags: java, array, arraylist, matriz

El problema comienza con el siguiente enunciado:
Se desea implementar una simulación de fantasmas moviéndose por un laberinto
(inspirada en Pacman). Para tal efecto se requiere implementar el ADT Laberinto
representado por una matriz de 0,1 donde el 0 representa camino y el 1 representa muro.
El constructor de Laberinto acepta un arreglo de String donde cada fila contienen los
0,1 que indican si hay camino o muro. Un método getPosicion(x,y) devuelve si hay
camino/muro en una posición del Laberinto. Un método dibujaLaberinto() dibuja el
laberinto.

Para esta parte ya tengo lo siguiente de codigo para que puedan entender mejor mi problema.

```
           import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;
           import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;


           /** 
            *
           * @author Tumac
           */
         public class LaberintoC implements Laberinto{

LaberintoC(String arreglo[]){
 
}

    @Override
      public String getPosition(int x, int y) {
            String[] data = {
            "1111111111111111111111111111111",
            "1010100010001000100010001000101",
            "1010101110111011101110111011101",
            "1000001000100000100000000000101",
            "1011111011111011101010101011101",
            "1000000000000000001010101010001",
            "1011101010101011111111111110101",
            "1000101010101000000000001000101",
            "1011101011111010101010111011111",
            "1010001000100010101010000000001",
            "1110111011101011111110111110111",
            "1000100010001000001000000010001",
            "1111111111111111111111111111111"
            };
            String r=null;
            if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 1){
                r="Muro";
                
            }else if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) 
             == 0){
                r= "Camino"; 
            }
                
            StdOut.println(r);
            return r;
    
    }
              @Override
            public void dibujaLaberinto(){
            String[] arreglo = {
            "1111111111111111111111111111111",
            "1010100010001000100010001000101",
            "1010101110111011101110111011101",
            "1000001000100000100000000000101",
            "1011111011111011101010101011101",
            "1000000000000000001010101010001",
            "1011101010101011111111111110101",
            "1000101010101000000000001000101",
            "1011101011111010101010111011111",
            "1010001000100010101010000000001",
            "1110111011101011111110111110111",
            "1000100010001000001000000010001",
            "1111111111111111111111111111111"
            };
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, 40);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, 40);
        for(byte i = 0;i<arreglo[1].length();i++){
            for(byte j =0;j<arreglo.length;j++){
                    int y = arreglo.length-1-j;
                    
              
             if(Character.getNumericValue(arreglo[y].charAt(i))==1) 
            {
                        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
                    }
                    else StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
                    StdDraw.filledSquare(i+0.5, j+0.5, 0.5);
                }
            }
            StdDraw.show();
}
```

}

Hasta el momento tengo el laberinto representado por medio de un arreglo, donde el 1 representa un muro y el 0 camino, en el cual debo situar un fantasma, entonces un
fantasma se describe por su posición actual (x,y) y la dirección en la que se mueve
(norte, sur, este, oeste) el fantasma se mueve en la dirección actual
hasta encontrar un muro. En ese momento, elige una nueva dirección al azar entre
aquellas donde hay camino. El Fantasma implementa un método mover() que mueve el
fantasma en la dirección actual o cambia de dirección si encuentra un muro.

Aqui muestro el laberinto:

```
       String[] data = { 
       "1111111111111111111111111111111",
       "1010100010001000100010001000101",
       "1010101110111011101110111011101",
       "1000001000100000100000000000101",
       "1011111011111011101010101011101",
       "1000000000000000001010101010001",
       "1011101010101011111111111110101",
       "1000101010101000000000001000101",
       "1011101011111010101010111011111",
       "1010001000100010101010000000001",
       "1110111011101011111110111110111",
       "1000100010001000001000000010001",
       "1111111111111111111111111111111" 
       };
```

Por el momento tengo esto pero no veo como una solucion clara, entonces esperaba que me pudieran orientar con esta logica por favor, muchas gracias!

```
            if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 1){
            }else if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 0){ 
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length;) {
                    if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 1){
                        x = x;
                        y = y;
                    }else if(Character.getNumericValue(data[x].charAt(y)) == 0){
                                  a = (int)(Math.random()*4);
                     switch (a) {
             case 0 ->
                 
                 x--;//Izquierda
             case 1 -> x++;//Derecha
             case 2 -> y++;//Arriba
             case 3 -> y--;//Abajo
             default -> {
             }
         }
                    }
          
                }
                
        
            }
```

Comment: sube tu codigo completo para tener un [mcve]

Comment: ¿No es más fácil hacer esto con una matriz (String [][] o incluso mejor int[][])? Creo que sería más fácil verificar los ejes x e y dentro de una matriz, también sería más fácil hacer x+1, x-1, y+1 y x-1 para verificar dónde hay una pared y "mover" el fantasma alrededor.

Comment: Si tienes razon, entonces como hago para meter cada elemento del vector a una matriz?